# Keep assigned Value in View State after Page Load

Tags: .net

How I can keep the same assigned value after page load in .NET? As after page load view state is getting refresh and value is showing blank.

Is there other way through which same can be manage, please suggest.

Comment: Show the code where the ViewState variable is cleared after pageload

Answer (score 0):

Forever? Hard coding into your site.

Changes based on user or administrative input? A database would be needed.

Changes on a per-user basis? Sessions.

Not sure what exactly you are going for, as this question can be a little broad.